# Is it even possible to install Spinnaker in an on premise RHEL box without internet connection?

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Is it even possible to install Spinnaker in an on premise RHEL box without internet connection ???

I am using halyard and even with using --no validate in all the commands it failes in the apply command looking for versions.yaml file. So is my following statement correct:

We can't install Spinnaker in an on premise RHEL box without internet connection!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using local git configuration

https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/environment/#local-git

Also you can configure hal to use different artifacts for spinnaker

https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/#deployments